# Runtime add and use database in laravel through the API's

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

**Runtime add and use database in laravel through the API's**

In my laravel application, one default database is there. After organization registration, **"runtime"** I have to create(or use) seperate database for that organization and after login, relevant organization data should be stored into its individual database.

Currently my '.env' file database code snippet:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=https://myproject.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myproject
DB_USERNAME=MyProject
DB_PASSWORD=MyPassword
```

Please suggest me logic for runtime database creation and use through the laravel API's.

Just for info, I am using Angular as a frontend.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this some type of multi tenancy project?

Comment: that kind of project